# How can I use .at method in pandas to return a particular data type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I use the `df.at[index, 'column']` is returning a string even though the column is of type `object`

I would like to return an `object` as is originally present in the column.

I have verified the column type using `df.dtypes` and it says `object` for the particular column

Comment: Data type `object` is Pandas' way to indicate that the column is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *object* type in *Pandas* means *something other then predefined
pandasonic numeric types*.

To check what type is in particulat cell, run:

```
type(df.at[index, 'column'])
```

and most likely you will get `'str'`.